# Eclipse Juno colored code folding areas

Tags: java, eclipse, code-folding

Recently I have started to experience issues with colored code folding in Eclipse. I would like to eliminate the colored regions in eclipse and just stick with a white background.

[image]

If anyone could help me get rid of the boxes and the green background I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT: Found out it isn't a Java specific problem. The same thing is happening when I open javascript files.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it finally. I needed to go into Preferences->EditBox then click on each color in the preview pane. Setting it anywhere else would not work.

[image]
H

Answer (score 1):

You can reset to default color scheme in Eclipse.

Navagate to **Windows>Preferences>Java>Editor**. Click on **Syntax Coloring**. Click "**Restore Defaults**" and "**Apply**". Then, navagate to **General>Editors**. Click on **Text Editors**. Click on "**Restore Defaults**" and "**Apply**".

Hope it works.